# Magento Frontend form date picker today date is wrong

Tags: magento-1.9, date

I want to setup date picker in frontend form,

and I did this currently,
datepicker is shown in a frontend form

only one issue is that when I click on today in datepicker it take the wrong date

screenshot: -

[image: http://prntscr.com/mzsyg5]

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                      //<![CDATA[
                          Calendar.setup({
                              inputField: "RebillStartDate",
                              ifFormat: "%d/%m/%Y",
                              showsTime: true,
                              button: "rebillstartdate",
                              align: "Bl",
                              singleClick : true
                            });
                     //]]>
</script>
```

Comment: you have set this way ..?

`$( ".selector" ).datepicker({
      dateFormat: "dd.mm.yy"
    });`

Default date format is `mm/dd/yy`

Comment: @RakeshDonga update my question with code

Comment: check this link mate : http://developersushant.blogspot.com/2015/01/magento-add-datepicker-to-contact-form.html also change ifFormat: "%m/%e/%Y"

Comment: follow the same but not work when click on today

Comment: i think problem in your create input field try this also i have tried in past this link and working for me : http://www.justwebdevelopment.com/blog/add-date-field-with-datepicker-in-magento/

Comment: working mate..?

Comment: calender is working fine , only problem is when i click on today it conduct the date of 2015

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91238/discussion-between-rakesh-donga-and-jigs-parmar).

Answer (score 0):

try it like this i know its too late but still if someone faces this kind of similar issue then this would be helpful

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                            require([
                                "jquery",
                                "mage/calendar"
                                ], function($){
  $('#datepicker').datepicker({
       prevText: '&#x3c;zurück', prevStatus: '',
        prevJumpText: '&#x3c;&#x3c;', prevJumpStatus: '',
        nextText: 'Vor&#x3e;', nextStatus: '',
        nextJumpText: '&#x3e;&#x3e;', nextJumpStatus: '',
        monthNames: ['Januar','Februar','März','April','Mai','Juni',
        'Juli','August','September','Oktober','November','Dezember'],
        monthNamesShort: ['Jan','Feb','Mär','Apr','Mai','Jun',
        'Jul','Aug','Sep','Okt','Nov','Dez'],
        dayNames: ['Sonntag','Montag','Dienstag','Mittwoch','Donnerstag','Freitag','Samstag'],
        dayNamesShort: ['So','Mo','Di','Mi','Do','Fr','Sa'],
        dayNamesMin: ['So','Mo','Di','Mi','Do','Fr','Sa'],
      showMonthAfterYear: false,
      dateFormat:'d.m.yy'
    } 
  );
                                });
</script>
```